# Recursively push the key value pair to hash with indiffernt access

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails and I am trying do something like,
I have hash

```
hash1 = {"a"=>"1","b"=>{"c"=>"3","d"=>{"e"=>"5"}},"f"=>"6","g"=>{"h"=>"7","i"=>"8"}}
```

Then i used a recursive method to read the key-value pair, as shown below :

```
def traverse_hash_recursively(words)
  words.each_pair do |key,value|
    if value.is_a?(String)
      puts "#{key}=>#{value}"
    else
      traverse_hash_recursively(value)
    end
  end
end
```

called the above method like this :

```
traverse_hash_recursively(hash1)
```

and the output is like :

```
a=>1
c=>3
e=>5
f=>6
h=>7
i=>8
```

But this is not the output i was looking for, i want the output as

```
hash[a]=1
hash[b][c]=3
hash[b][d][e]=5
hash[f]=6
hash[g][h]=7
hash[g][i]=8
```

I know what i have written in the code will give me the output i got but how will i get the desired output?
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

We need a stack that will keep track of the keys

```
def traverse_hash_recursively(keys, words)
  words.each_pair do |key,value| 
    keys << key
    if value.is_a?(String)
      puts "#{keys.join(',')}=>#{value}"
      keys.pop
    else
      traverse_hash_recursively(keys, value)
      keys.pop
    end
  end
end
```

And you should call the function with an empty stack.

```
traverse_hash_recursively([], hash1)
```

Output =>

```
a=>1
b,c=>3
b,d,e=>5
f=>6
g,h=>7
g,i=>8
```

Now, the rest is just formatting.